# Audio not playing on the front: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: python, flask, html5-audio

I am having a problem with audio playback at the front. This problem is only present when deploying to prod. When launched locally, audio is played. When I launch it on production, when I play audio (via the a tag), I get the following message: *Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME*.

Can you please tell me which way to look, where to look for a solution? I've already googled everything and zero information. I would be extremely grateful. Thank you.

Backend on Flask:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, Response, request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(name)
CORS(app)

def generate_wav(path: str, count_read=65536):    
    with open(path, "rb") as fio:
        data = fio.read(count_read)
        while data:
            yield data
            data = fio.read(count_read)

@app.route("/get-wav")
def get_wav():
    path = request.args.get('path')    
    return Response(generate_wav(path), mimetype="audio/x-wav")
```

Frontend, working version (local):

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="localhost:5000/get-wav?path=/full_path/file.wav" type="audio/wave">
    <p>
        Your browser does not support HTML5 <code>audio</code>.
        To listen, click on <a href="localhost:5000/get-wav?path=/full_path/file.wav">link</a>
    </p>
</audio>
```

Frontend, non-working version on prod (another computer):

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="external_address.com/get-wav?path=/full_path/file.wav" type="audio/wav">
    <p>
        Your browser does not support HTML5 <code>audio</code>.
        To listen, click on <a href="external_address.com/get-wav?path=/full_path/file.wav">link</a>
    </p>
</audio>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors thrown? Either in the browser console or api logs? Also, the frontend code for type="audio/wav" for local is wrong?

Comment: What is really "external_address.com"? Obfuscation makes things more complicated to understand and hence to reply to.

Comment: @coldy Error is thrown only in the browser console - net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME. Unfortunately, this is all by error. Frontend code for type="audio/wav" (or type="audio/wave", this is the same) works when run locally. At the same time, if you get the link from source tag (<source src="...">) via google chrome and paste it in the new tab - audio works fine.

Comment: @patrick-mevzek "external_address.com" is just remote ip address with port (for example, http://172.16.1.1:5678) or remote domain name (http://external_address.com).

Comment: Put a real URL then, starting with `http://` or `https://`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Danil, the below are some of the options which you can try:

### One:

According to [net-informations](http://net-informations.com/q/mis/scheme.html) the error `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` is caused when the default http or https are not the types to `<a href="url"></a>`. They suggest adding `target="_blank"` to avoid the issue. I personally feel it could be also the way the api itself is designed. For that, please look to option three.

### Two:

Using jinja template instead of html. You can change the plain html into jinja to see if that functions as expected.

From:

```
@app.route("/get-wav")
def get_wav():
    path = request.args.get('path')    
    return Response(generate_wav(path), mimetype="audio/x-wav")

<audio controls>
    <source src="localhost:5000/get-wav?path=/full_path/file.wav" type="audio/wave">
    <p>
        Your browser does not support HTML5 <code>audio</code>.
        To listen, click on <a href="localhost:5000/get-wav?path=/full_path/file.wav">link</a>
    </p>
</audio>
```

To:

```
@app.route("/get-wav/<string:name>")
def get_wav():
    path = os.path.join("your/absolute/base_dir", name)    
    return Response(generate_wav(path), mimetype="audio/x-wav")

<audio controls>
    <source src="{{ url_for("get_wav", name=file.wav) }}" type="audio/wav">
    <p>
        Your browser does not support HTML5 <code>audio</code>.
        To listen, click on <a href="{{ url_for("get_wav", name=file.wav) }}">link</a>
    </p>
</audio>
```

### Three:

Your current api is designed as follows, `https://api.domain.com/get-wav?path=/full_path/file.wav`. This design would make the path vulnerable and exposed to be retrieved. Hence, I would propose you try the uploads folder option provided from flask and implement it accordingly.

A simple example based on [flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/) documentation:

You will first need to set the uploads folder

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads' # This is the top level folder name of your wav files
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'wav', 'mp3'} # Supported extensions

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

Now, when you want to get a wav file, then do the following:

```
from flask import send_from_directory

    @app.route('/uploads/<name>')
    def get_wav(name):
        # Here, you can use the name to perform some operations, such as generate_wav. But, if you are not generating the wav you could also return an already generated one here using send_from_directory.
        return send_from_directory(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], name)
```

Finally, you will have to use jinja to source the api as file and obtain it as follows:

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="{{ url_for("get_wav", name=file.wav) }}" type="audio/wav">
    <p>
        Your browser does not support HTML5 <code>audio</code>.
        To listen, click on <a href="{{ url_for("get_wav", name=file.wav) }}">link</a>
    </p>
</audio>
```

Some References:

1. [Handling File uploads](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/handling-file-uploads-with-flask)
2. [Flask file uploads](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/)
3. [jinja2](https://jinja2docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/nativetypes.html#examples)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Before posting the question here, I tried 1. It didn't help. For 2, I've simplified the code so that it has this problem and is easy to read. The 3rd point solved my problem. With the send_from_directory function, everything works. Great, thank you!

Comment: If the answer has helped, consider accepting it for the question. Thanks